# Downloading files from server using PHP

Tags: php, apache, download

I am having a web server in which there are 1000 files in a folder with the following name:

```
1.txt
2.txt
3.txt
.
.
.
1000.txt
```

Note: files might be in some other format also. Like JPEG, PNG etc. 
I want to download them all using PHP (I am having access to that folder).

I am trying to use the following algorithm:

```
for (i=1 to 1000)
{
     $link = "http://xyz.com/pqr/".$i.".txt";
     fopen($link);
     /*download -- how to?*/
}
```

Is this method correct? How to copy / download it into my local machine?

Answer (score 2):

Use this: http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php

And then save the value in a file with the same name locally: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fwrite.php

Comment: Should work, since it's binary-safe. You can also try http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php instead of fwrite

Answer (score 2):

You can use [cURL](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php):

```
function get_data($link)
{
    $ch = curl_init();
    $timeout = 5;
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $link);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $data;
}
```